# Unable to Resolve Service Type using AWS Net Core 3.1 Secrets.json set up

Tags: asp.net, .net

I used [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/user-secrets-in-a-net-core-web-app-html) tutorial to hide sensitive information in the secret.json.

This is the exception I get

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
```

This is startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<AmeritradeAccountDetails>(Configuration.GetSection("AmeritradeAccountDetails"))
```

This is in appsettings.json that are overrun by secrets.json

```
"AmeritradeAccountDetails": {
"ApiKey": " For development, set in User Secrets"
},
```

This is the model AmeritradeAccountDetails.cs

```
public class AmeritradeAccountDetails
{
        public string ApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
private readonly AmeritradeAccountDetails _ameritradeAccountDetails;
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
       return _ameritradeAccountDetails.ApiKey;
    }
```

Comment: there are several suspicious areas in your code (or at least in the code that you posted). Does it work if you store values in `appsettings.json`? How do you load `secrets.json`? How do you inject `AmeritradeAccountDetails` into controller? You need to do some debugging; *not* expect that others will read the tutorial in order to help you.

Comment: @Felix It does not work with the values in appsettings.json either.  I appears they don't like the model file, AmeritradeAccountDetails.cs but I do not see what is wrong with it.